# How are you supposed to win the first battle for the final chapter?

Tags: clash-of-heroes

The chapter starts and you're immediately met [with a boss fight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eGO9.jpg) between a rather weak foe and my strongest character (the Necromancer). Sounds like a piece of cake — his units are undeleveled and I can deal 75% more damage with my units thanks to the Spider Cloak.

Things take a turn for the wrong when you complete a turn and the third row of your battlefield is outlined in orange circles. Basically, *this guy destroys everything on your second and third line every other round.* Even if I create a bunch of walls there, they get destroyed like everything else only for my units to advance to their doom one turn later.

I suppose that I'm supposed to rely on my rather awesome spell attack for this, but it takes quite a while to charge and, in the meantime, I'm being attacked with everything he's got.

What the hell is going on and how are you supposed to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Only* equip ghosts as your special formation. Once the ghost formation is made, they become invulnerable to those undue explosions.

Don't forget to equip an artefact! For this fight I suggest the Ritual Dagger; all moves not spent making ghost formations are useless in this fight, so you might as well spend them to slow the enemy down.